# javascript compare graphically two JSON/XML objects

Tags: javascript, json, compare

I am trying to build a web application that a JavaScript graphical comparison/representation
of two XML/JSON data objects, so the user would be able to merge between them.
Does anybody know about any available code that does something like this?

Comment: This question is not very clear. The term, "XML/JSON data object" could mean anything at all. It's also not clear what "graphical comparison" might mean, or what "merging" might mean.

Comment: I have two complex hierarchical JSON objects as my data objects. I would like to have some graphical tree representation where I had in mind something like Beyond Compare or meld but for JSON data and well I guess the merge would follow the same graphical interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab, but the question isn't too clear... Compare the two XML strings with this: http://snowtide.com/jsdifflib